# LINQ for a list of list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
  public class Employee
    { 
        public string  Name{get;set;}
        public List<Department> Department { get; set; }
        public string Company{get;set;}
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

   List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee() { Company = "Dell", Name = "ABC" });
        employees.Add(new Employee() { Company = "Dell", Name = "Aakash" });
        employees.Add(new Employee() { Company = "CSC", Name = "Vaibhav" });
        employees.Add(new Employee() { Company = "TCS", Name = "Sambhav" });

        employees[0].Department = new List<Department>();
        employees[0].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Delhi", Name = "HR" });
        employees[0].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Delhi", Name = "Recruitment" });

        employees[1].Department = new List<Department>();
        employees[1].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Noida", Name = "EAO" });
        employees[1].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Delhi", Name = "Arch" });

        employees[2].Department = new List<Department>();
        employees[2].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Denmark", Name = "Scandi" });
        employees[2].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Noida", Name = "SAG" });

        employees[3].Department = new List<Department>();
        employees[3].Department.Add(new Department() { Location = "Mumbai", Name = "NSE" });
```

I need to write a lambda expression to select all employees where Departement Location is Noida

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Any` extension method:

```
var results = employees.Where(e => e.Department.Any(d => d.Location == "Noida"))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure the `ToList()` is necessary but +1.

Comment: You have another questions? Ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you even don't need LINQ for that. `List<T>` has methods [FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) and [Exsists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) which can do the job:

```
employees.FindAll(e => e.Department.Exists(d => d.Location == "Noida"))
```